# Error message: does not implement inherited abstract member

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract

Beware, cause I'm newbie with C#! So I have a regular class `Cube` that inherits from an abstract class `Shape3D` which in turn inherits from an abstract class `Shape2D`.

`Shape2D`provides, among other things, two abstract properties:  `Area` & `Perimeter`. The `Cube` constructor calls the base class constructor, and sets a new objects length, height and width.

For some reason, I get this error from `Cube`:

```
Error: 'Cube' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Shape2D.Area.get'
Error: 'Cube' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Shape2D.Perimeter.get'
```

This is how `Shape2D` looks:

```
abstract class Shape2D : Shape
{
    private double _length, _width;
    public double Length{..}
    public double Width{..}

    public abstract double Area{ get; }

    public abstract double Perimeter{ get; }

    protected Shape2D(ShapeType shapeType, double length, double width) 
    : base(shapeType)
    {
        _length = length;
        _width = width;
    }

    public override string ToString(){..}
}
```

`Shape 3D`:

```
abstract class Shape3D : Shape2D
{
    protected Shape2D _baseShape;
    private double _height;

    public double Height{..}
    public virtual double MantelArea{..}
    public virtual double TotalSurfaceArea{..}
    public virtual double Volume{..}

    protected Shape3D(ShapeType shapeType, Shape2D baseShape, double height)
    : base(shapeType, height, height)
    {
        _baseShape = baseShape;
        _height = height;
    }

    public override string ToString(){..}
}
```

`Cube`:

```
class Cube : Shape3D --> This returns inherited error.
{
    ...
}
```

I've google my a** off, and haven't found anything useful. Why does my regular class not inherit abstract members from an abstract class? Can anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your 2d class is abstract with two abstract properties, you need to implement them in your concrete class as shown below.

Quick edit to answer your question - The properties are abstract that's why it appears not to 'inherit' them.  You need to implement any abstract properties when making a concrete implementation.  In case you're thinking you should change these from abstract on your 2dShape, they should probably stay abstract there because different shapes will have different formulas for calculating perimeter & area based on the lengths & widths.

```
class Cube : Shape3D
{
   public override double Area{ get; }

    public override double Perimeter{ get; }

}
```

Comment: Hmm yeah, that avoids the error. I'm following an implementation where the cube class does not involve having two override methods for Area and Perimeter, but I can't see how else that would work! In the example I'm following, the cube class only has a constructor method..

Comment: if you provide a link to the example I can take a look at it.

Comment: I did follow the pictures... Cube inherits from shape, not 2d shape.  Now that I think about it, perimeter & area don't make sense for a cube.  Volume & surface area would make sense for a cube.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. So why is it giving me trouble with inheriting Area and Perimeter? The cube will inherit features from the Rectangle class, so I guess perimeter & area makes some kind of sense for the cube

Comment: Sorry I mistyped.  Cube inherits from 3D shape, 3DShape inherits from Shape.  Rectangle inherits from 2DShape, 2DShape inherits from shape.  So even though both Rectangle & Cube have Length & Width as properties, they're not really related to each other.  They just share a common ancestor that only has Is3D & ShapeType as properties.

Comment: because you're doing this: abstract class Shape3D : Shape2D 
when you should be doing this: abstract class Shape3D : Shape

Comment: I had completely misread the relations between the classes. Thank you for clearing that up for me hehe :)